# Merging two CSV files on common column - result: empty

Tags: python, csv, merge

I have two CSV files:

- Filmdata: UserID, Age of User, FilmID, Sex of User
- FilmNames: FilmID (which is the common column) and FilmName

I would like to merge those two files, so that I have one CSV file with UserID, Age, FilmID, Sex and FilmName (based on FilmID).

I am using the following code snippet:

```
import pandas as pd

a = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Alex/Box Sync/CS109/Predictions/FilmDaten.csv.csv")
b = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Alex/Box Sync/CS109/Predictions/FilmnamenNEU.csv.csv")
b = b.dropna(axis=1)
merged = a.merge(b, on='FilmID')
merged.to_csv("C:/Users/Alex/Box Sync/CS109/Predictions/Filmoutput.csv", index=False)
```

`FilmDaten.csv` looks like this:

```
UserID,Alter,Geschlecht,Beruf,PLZ,FilmID,Bewertung
1,24,M,technician,85711,61,4
1,24,M,technician,85711,189,3
```

`FilmnamenNEU.csv` like this:

```
FilmID, FilmNamen
1, Toy Story
2, Jurassic Parc
```

When I do this the *column names* do indeed merge, however the `FilmName` column in the output file remains empty. Does anyone know a solution?

Comment: Hi, if I use the same FilmID (1 and 2) in both the 'sample csvs', I get a proper 2x8 dataframe. So for the case where you are 'merging' indeed the filmnames don't exist? and hence empty?

Comment: Hi, but the FIlmNames are clearly there in the FilmNamenNeu file. I just tried it again and they are still missing in the output file...

Comment: By the way, it does not even work for me when using just the sample code from above. I only get the header/column names (including the FilmNames, which is correct), but the actual columns are empty.

Comment: Which is expected in your dataset. The `FilmID` in fildaten.csv is 61, 189 and filmID in filmnamen.csv is 1,2 - obviously there are no common filmIDs, so the result set is an empty set. Is this not correct? or I am missing something? Based on your explanation what I thought was only filmNames column was empty but others were right, so I was wondering - what the data is like.

Comment: Hi there, thanks! FilmIDs 61 und 189 belong to different movies - those are not depicted in the sample files here. FilmID 1 is Toy Story, for instance. So I would have expected the merging to take place so that all FilmID 1 values are subsumed under Toy Story. But as I said, I don't even get to properly merge them.

Comment: Only more relevant data could help. for instance in the example data - when I changed filmID to 1 and 2, I was able to get non-empty filmName value.